# Facebook Login verification (business)

Tags: facebook-login

I'm building a simple app and I wanted to put that Login with Facebook button. I've done it in development so I need to verify my app to use it in production.

On the first try, I created a business account with the app name. Now, I can not verify it or delete it (it doesn't allow). I spent quite some time to reach out to support but I guess it's impossible.

Anyway, I'm an individual who wants to use Facebook Login, and I have a business account linked to my app and I can not verify or remove/delete. What should I do?